For any class $C$, can the existence of $\bigcap C$ cause issues in ZFC?
My understanding is as follows: for any class $C$ containing at least one set $x$, the set
$$\bigcap C$$
exists. I've read that if no set is in $C$, then $\bigcap C$ is a proper class. My question is as follows: would allowing the existence (as sets) of such an arbitrary intersection cause inconsistency issues?

Yes, if we are working with classes (e.g. $\mathsf {NBG}$) we have that $\bigcap\emptyset = \text V$, where $\text V$ is the universal class (see Mendelson, page 244).
In $\mathsf {ZF}$ we have that there is no "universal set". Thus, the usual trick is to define $\bigcap \emptyset = \emptyset$.
Another possibility is to left it undefined, like division by zero (see discussion in Enderton, page 25).
Intuition: what are the elements of $A \cap B$? those $x$ that belong to both $A$ and $B$.
Thus, what are the elements of $\bigcap C$? those $x$ that belong to every element of $C$, that is:

$x \in \bigcap C \text { iff } \forall z [ z \in C \to x \in z]$.

The issue when $C=\emptyset$ is that no $z \in\emptyset$, and thus the condition $z \in C \to x \in z$ holds for every $x$.

If $C$ is inhabited then $\bigcap C$ is a set, basically by the axiom of separation applied to any member of $C$.
No extra axioms needed.
Indeed, by definition, $x \in \bigcap C$ if and only if $\forall (c \in C) (x \in c)$, and for all $c' \in C$, $\{ x \in c' : \forall (c \in C) (x \in c) \}$ is a set and equal to $\bigcap C$; so we just apply existential instantiation to conclude that $\bigcap C$ is a set.
But if $C$ is empty then $\bigcap C$ contains everything, so it cannot be a set (in set theories where Cantor's theorem is valid, anyway).
